# Make DIV's expand outwards from center div instead of inwards

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**I have three divs in a row**

One on the left, one in the middle and one on the right.

The one's on the left and right need to expand *AWAY* from the one in the middle.

Please see image:

[image]

**my clients.php which displays them all**

```
echo "<div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block;'>";

while ($client = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $positive = $client['Pos'];
    $negative = $client['Neg'];
    $total = ($positive + $negative);

    // Calculate width in percentage
    if ($total > 0) 
    {
        $positiveWidth = ($positive/$total)*100;
        $negativeWidth = ($negative/$total)*100; 
    }
    else
    {
        $positiveWidth = "0%";
        $negativeWidth = "0%";
    }


    echo "<div class='clientid' style='height: 50px; font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 100%'>" . 

            "
            <div class='positive-bar' style='width: $positiveWidth;%;'></div>

            <div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>      
                <span style='font-size: 20px;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-up vote-up'></span>
            </div>" .

                 "<div id='client-name' class='hover-cursor hvr-underline-reveal voteup votedown' data-clientid='{$client['ClientID']}' style='width: 20%; display: inline-block;'>" . $client['Client'] . "</div>" . 

            "<div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>
                <span style='font-size: 20px; text-align: right;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-down vote-down'></span>
            </div>

            <div class='negative-bar' style='width: $negativeWidth;%;'></div>

         </div> 
        <br />";
}

echo "</div>";
```

This means that also the divs only get as big as you see in the image and push the text out of the center.

**The relevant piece of CSS:**

```
.positive-bar
{
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #64BE06;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.negative-bar
{
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

***So my question is***
How can i make the DIV's (Progress bars) Expand outwards instead of pushing in.

Comment: could you give your feedback on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it using `flexbox`

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  margin:5px 0;
}
.middleOne{
  flex-grow:1;
  height:25px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.rightOne,.leftOne{
  height:25px;
  width:25%;
  min-width:100px;
  border:1px solid green;
  display:flex;
}
.leftOne{
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
.rightOne{
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
.progress{
  background-color:green;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:70%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleOne">Content Here</div>
  <div class="rightOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:50%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleOne">Content Here</div>
  <div class="rightOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:30%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleOne">Content Here</div>
  <div class="rightOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:80%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleOne">Content Here</div>
  <div class="rightOne">
    <div class="progress" style="width:0%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT : specific for The code OP gave in comments**

I suggest you to make these changes (line numbers are the line numbers from this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/quhQxyde) you gave)

- Line 81  ::  `$positiveWidth = 0;`
- Line 82  ::  `$negativeWidth = 0;`
- Line 89  ::  `<div class='positive-bar hover-cursor' style='width:
  ".$positiveWidth."%;'></div>`
- Line 103 ::  `<div class='negative-bar hover-cursor' style='width:
  ".$negativeWidth."%;'></div>`

Comment: so why `text-align:center` for the middle one instead of `justify-content: center;`

Comment: @sweaver2112   `justify-content: center;` is used for elements that are set to `display:flex;` it aligns all the child element to horizontally centered whether thay are `<div>` or `<a>` or `<img>`. `text-align:center;` can be used on any element to center the text within. Don't mind leaving an upvote if you like the answer.

Comment: but the middle div is display:flex as well. are you saying both would work?

Comment: If you are talking about the snippet in my answer. `.middleOne` is not set to `display:flex;`, maybe you are confusing `flex-grow:1;` with `display:flex;`. But if you are asking in general then yes. The text in the `.middleOne` will center if you remove `text-align:center;` and add `display:flex; justify-content:center;`